# Rebuild a workbook with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run the below VBA that I found online. The purpose of the code is to copy the data from all of the worksheets in a workbook to a different workbook. A couple key points:

1) I am trying to copy the data in all worksheets NOT the actual worksheets to the new workbook
 2) The macro does a lot: makes sure you have a back-up file; creates a new worksheet (TargetWorkbook) and saves with the source workbook's name; etc. however, the most important part (and where I believe it is erroring) is copying the worksheets
 3) I understand what is going on with the code but not savvy enough to make it work.

```
Sub Update_SmartView_Workbook()
' Copies sheets from a source workbook to new and current Excel target workbook to
' get rid of the "2003 or earlier backbone" that interferes with SmartView.
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+z
' Copyleft 2013 By MJ Henderson. No rights reserved. Free and worth every penny. 
' User assumes all risk. No warranties implied or otherwise.

    Dim ConfirmBackup As Integer
    Dim SourceWorkbook, TargetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceWorkbookName As String

    ' User must make a backup before proceeding.
    ConfirmBackup = MsgBox("Have you made a backup copy of the source file?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Backup")
    If ConfirmBackup = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "Try again when you have a backup copy of the source file", vbOKOnly, "Backup Required"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Find and open the source file
    Application.FindFile
    Set SourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    SourceWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Len(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) - Len(SourceWorkbookName))

    ' Create a new target workbook in the same folder as the source workbook
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & "TargetWorkbook.xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=True

    ' Copy each worksheet in SourceWorkbook to TargetWorkbook THIS IS WHERE THE FIX IS NEEDED
    SourceWorkbook.Activate
    For Each SourceWorksheet In SourceWorkbook.Worksheets
    SourceWorksheet.Cells.Copy
    Windows("TargetWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    On Error Resume Next
    TargetWorkbook.Sheets(SourceWorksheet.Name).Delete
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = SourceWorksheet.Name
    Application.CutCopyMode = cancel
    Next

    ' Close SourceWorkbook, rename SourceWorkbook with suffix "_OLD"
    SourceWorkbook.Activate
    SourceWorkbook.Saved = True
    SourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Name SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & SourceWorkbookName As SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & SourceWorkbookName & "_OLD"

    ' Global replace to remove any references to old workbook. (Fixes interbook links.)
    Cells.Replace What:="[" & SourceWorkbookName & "]", _
    Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    ' Rename TargetWorkbook as SourceWorkbook's original name, delete TargetWorkbook
    TargetWorkbook.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & SourceWorkbookName, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Kill SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & "TargetWorkbook.xlsx"

End Sub
```

I believe these lines are driving the error:

```
 Windows("TargetWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
 ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
```

The error I am getting is "Run Time Error 9 - Subscript out of Range"

Any idea on how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Workbooks("TargetWorkbook.xlsx").Activate` instead of `Windows...`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to eliminate the activating if the sheet and workbooks; we do not need it. Just referencing the object is enough.

This is an untested code see how it goes you might need to change it a little bit to fit your needs.

```
Option Explicit
```

Sub Test()

```
Dim ConfirmBackup As Integer
Dim SourceWorkbook, TargetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim SourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim SourceWorkbookName As String
Dim SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath As String

' User must make a backup before proceeding.
ConfirmBackup = MsgBox("Have you made a backup copy of the source file?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Backup")
If ConfirmBackup = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "Try again when you have a backup copy of the source file", vbOKOnly, "Backup Required"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Find and open the source file
Application.FindFile
Set SourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
SourceWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Len(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) - Len(SourceWorkbookName))

' Create a new target workbook in the same folder as the source workbook
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & "TargetWorkbook.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ConflictResolution:=True

' Copy each worksheet in SourceWorkbook to TargetWorkbook THIS IS WHERE THE FIX IS NEEDED
For Each SourceWorksheet In SourceWorkbook.Worksheets
    TargetWorkbook.Sheets(SourceWorksheet.Name).Delete
    SourceWorksheet.Copy After:=TargetWorkbook.Sheets(TargetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
Next

' Close SourceWorkbook, rename SourceWorkbook with suffix "_OLD"
SourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Name SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & SourceWorkbookName As SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & SourceWorkbookName & "_OLD"

' Global replace to remove any references to old workbook. (Fixes interbook links.)
Cells.Replace What:="[" & SourceWorkbookName & "]", _
              Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
              False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

' Rename TargetWorkbook as SourceWorkbook's original name, delete TargetWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & SourceWorkbookName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Kill SourceWorkbookDirectoryPath & "TargetWorkbook.xlsx"
```

End Sub

I hope it helps